# why does it give me POST http://localhost:3000/process-payment 404 (Not Found) when the endpoint in server.js is declared

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, backend, json-api

this is my angular typescript component for my stripe payment, in which i want the money from the pay(...) method to go to an attribute of a json rest api database, and maybe mongodb database later, what could be the cause of the endpoint not being found

```
  pay(amount: any) {
    var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_51OKda9H5eXnyJcWfb1dh0tGzXv2FclyLrDzPCqL5SGsyuDmZr2ljbfquR7kMZaRVONanewECDPXfPWswAiKQvuxl009QOEIECu',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: (token: any) => {
        console.log(token.id);
        console.log(token);
        alert('Token Created!!');

       ` // Attempt to reach the server endpoint`
        this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/process-payment', { token, amount })
          .subscribe((response: any) => {
            if (response.success) {
              console.log('Payment success!');
              // Update client-side logic as needed
            }
          });
      }
    });


  }
}
```

server.js

```
// Express server with Stripe integration
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const stripe = require('stripe')('my live stripe key');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Endpoint for processing payments
app.post('/process-payment', async (req, res) => {
  const { token, amount } = req.body;

  try {
    // Create a payment intent or charge using Stripe API
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: amount * 100, // Amount in cents
      currency: 'usd', // Change to your desired currency
      payment_method: token.id,
      confirmation_method: 'manual',
      confirm: true,
    });

    // Update balance in your JSON REST API database
    const userId = req.user.id; // Replace this with your user identification logic
    const userBalance = await Balance.findOne({ userId });

    if (userBalance) {
      userBalance.amount += amount;
      await userBalance.save();
    } else {
      // Create a new balance entry if not exists
      await Balance.create({ userId, amount });
    }

    res.json({ success: true, paymentIntent });
  } catch (error) {
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't speak to why the endpoint isn't found. You'll need to add more diagnostics to debug that. Are you able to reach any other endpoints on your express server? Your client code appears to be using Legacy Checkout which has been deprecated for several years and should not be used for any new development. You'll want to replace that with a modern Elements or Checkout integration: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/checkout/migration

Comment: yeah, ill change the component, i can reach the database and the users one by one, ill see if changing the component fixes the issue(i doubt it but still)